# Regex values in JSON response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, response

I want to regex JSON response value in AJAX without losing the structure of JSON.
Here is the ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "date.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var formDatax = new FormData();
        var date = data.results;
        var res = date.map(function(item) {
            return { 
            "images": item.images
            };
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "json.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(res),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            },
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    },
    error: function() {}
});
```

Here is an example of JSON Response

```
{  
      "part_number_key":"DDASDAS",
      "name":"ASD",
      "description":"asd",
      "price":12,
      "general_stock":12,
      "brand":"ASD",
      "category_id":2776,
      "images":[  
         {  
            "url":"https://asd.com/asd/asd/1241.jpg",
            "display_type":1
         },
         {  
            "url":"https://asd.com/asd/asd/73223.jpg",
            "display_type":0
         },
         {  
            "url":"https://asd.com/asd/asd/214121.jpg",
            "display_type":0
         }
      ],
      "warranty":24
   },
```

I want to get the link of the image where the display_type is having value 1, so I thought it's ok if I regex the first url before "display_type":1 but I'm not able because this is not string to regex.

`/(https?\:\/\/[^\" ][^]).*("display_type":1)/i`

The regex, it's not complete because I saw the problem about the string I didn't tried to complete the regex...

Comment: you'll have to parse the json

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(responseString)` then look for images in your json `<jsonObject>.images.forEach(item => {if item["display_type"] == 1 ....})`

Comment: JSON and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the JSON and use filter and map to get the images URL

```
success: function(data) {
   var response = JSON.parse(data)
   var imagesURL = response.images.filter(image => image.display_type).map(image => image.url)
}
```

Comment: `var imagesURL = item.images.filter(image => image.display_type === 1).map(image => image.url)`
Was the right way for me because it was insite of res variable.

THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!

Comment: One more question, I saw one more problem just now... 
Some responses have value of true, not of 1, I tried
`var imagesURL = item.images.filter(image => image.display_type === 1 && image.display_type === true).map(image => image.url)`
to check of multiple conditions but doesn't work and I don't really know how .filter it's working, I tried to search on google but I saw only different structures of function.

Comment: `var imagesURL = item.images.filter(image => image.display_type === 1).map(image => image.url)
var imagesURLtr = item.images.filter(image => image.display_type === true).map(image => image.url)
                    console.log(imagesURL);
                    if (imagesURL.length > 0) {
var imagesURLf = item.images.filter(image => image.display_type === 1).map(image => image.url)
}else if (imagesURLtr.length > 0) {
var imagesURLf = item.images.filter(image => image.display_type === true).map(image => image.url)
}`

I did that and now it's ok!

Comment: In your try you used the && conditional, but display_type can't be true AND 1. You should use || to be true OR 1. In my edited answer you can see that I don't compare display_type , Javascript will check automatically if the variable is true or 1

Answer (score 0):

The response type is always parsed JSON. You can just access the images which have `display_type: 1` like so:

```
let fileterImages = data.data.images.map((image) => {
  if(image.display_type === 1) return image.url;
}
```